# Printing integer in hexadecimal with Elixir

Tags: elixir, string-formatting

I can do this in Erlang:

```
io:fwrite("~.16X~n", [-31,"0x"]).
-0x1F
ok
```

but not in Elixir:

`:io.fwrite("~.16X~n", [-31,"0x"])
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :io.format(#PID<0.54.0>, "~.16X~n", [-31, "0x"])`

Why not?

Comment: Try single quotes: `:io.fwrite('~.16X~n', [-31, '0x'])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding @Dogbert's comment as an answer:

Try using single quotes:

```
:io.fwrite('~.16X~n', [-31, '0x'])
```

A word of additional explanation: single quotes in Elixir indicate a character list (see [here](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#charlists) for more details).  The Erlang `fwrite` function is expecting a list of characters not an Elixir binary hence the double quotes don't work while the single quotes do.

Answer (score 7):

Why not to use `Integer.to_string/2`?

```
iex(1)> Integer.to_string(-31, 16)
"-1F"
```